# Optimize Sitecore Publishing to Edge target

Tags: publishing, experience-edge, edge

We are facing performance issues while publishing to Edge. It takes more time to publish to Edge when compared to publishing to a web database. We understand that publishing to a database target is totally different to publishing to Edge. We are looking into any opportunities to optimize publishing to Edge. I was checking below Sitecore documentation on configuring publishing performance. Looks like by tuning configurations we can optimize the publish performance. Sitecore do not have any recommendations to tune the configurations so wanted to check with the Sitecore community as to how the tuning can be done and how each of the configurations will impact the publish performance

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/21/sitecore-headless-development/configuring-publishing-performance.html

We are using Sitecore version 10.3 and Edge Connecter 21.x.

Comment: There are lots of blogs/articles related to improving publishing performance available online in Sitecore. But your usecase is specific to publishing to Edge. You should create a Sitecore support ticket to look deeper into this.

Comment: I had raised a sitecore support ticket but they informed that there is no recommendation from sitecore except the document which I mentioned in the description. After that only I thought maybe some one in Sitecore community might have experimented with tuning the publish performance.